# Concavity condition for function of more than one variable

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

We know for single variable function $f(t)$, the necessary and sufficient condition for *concavity* is

$$ f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y) \ge (1-\lambda)f(x)-\lambda f(y)   $$ for every $x$ and $y$ and $0 \le \lambda \le 1$.

**Question**: 
         How to define concavity condition for function of more than one variable? for instance for function of three variables $f(r,s,t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is exactly the same. If $A$ is a convex subset of a real vector space $V$, and $f: A \to \Bbb{R}$ is a function, then $f$ is concave whenever $$f((1- \lambda)x + \lambda y) \ge (1- \lambda)f(x) + \lambda f(y)$$ for all $x,y \in A$, and for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$.
Here $x,y$ are meant as vectors, and this condition does not require that the dimension of $V$ is finite.

So, for example, if $A \subset \Bbb{R}^2$ (i.e. $f$ has two variables), the condition becomes
$$f((1- \lambda)x_1 + \lambda y_1 , (1- \lambda)x_2 + \lambda y_2) \ge (1- \lambda)f(x_1, x_2) + \lambda f(y_1,y_2)$$
for all $(x_1, x_2) , (y_1, y_2) \in A$, and for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$.